# Jquery select element from data attribute that is stored in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have many divs with class `.modal-dialog` and a data field like `data-modal='student'` and set it to `display:none`

I select and store it on variable like

```
    modal_dialog= $('.modal-dialog')
```

Now I need to show modal with a particular data-modal attribute.

I tried

```
modal_dialog.hasData('student').show();
modal_dialog.data('student').show();
```

but didn't work. Any idea how to get this work?

Comment: Please [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+select+data+attribute) before you ask a new question.

Comment: Those does not have selection variables. I am not dumb to post question right away.

Comment: Ah now, I see. Use `.filter` then: http://api.jquery.com/filter/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`.filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
foo.filter('[data-bar="baz"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data field is an actual attribute, you can do

```
$('.modal-dialog[data-modal]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look for the actual value in `data-modal`,

```
$('.modal-dialog[data-modal="student"]').show();
```